# I try to install wine after deleted it once and when i try to install it again it said this. I don't know what to do i try everything already

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg, wine

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine : Depends: wine64 (>= 5.0-3ubuntu1) or
wine32 (>= 5.0-3ubuntu1)
Depends: wine64 (< 5.0-3ubuntu1.1~) or
wine32 (< 5.0-3ubuntu1.1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

(Extra information: unbuntu 20.04 i have dowload it once but deleted it again bc i dowload the wrong wine version and when i try to dowload the correct one it's said that)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? How did you install and "delete"?

Comment: It smells like you tried to cleverly install Wine using some random online instructions, and it failed, and then you neglected to clean up the mess. Now that mess is blocking any other method of installing. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1455847/edit) to provide a link to the instructions that you followed, and clearly describe which step went wrong and exactly how.

Comment: Since Wine is already in the Ubuntu repositories, and trivial to install, most of our advice will be about cleaning up your clever previous attempt(s).